# Binding ComboBox to DataGrid Entry

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, wpfdatagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

*Solved problem, but still have questions.  See end of post, or read on for context.*

I'm trying to setup a WPF datagrid which has many templated columns with comboboxes inside of them.  In particular I'm having trouble with data-binding.

**Data Model**
First, I have `Entry`, which contains 4 properties:

- `Name`
- `Customer`
- `Color`
- `Type`

The most interesting property is `Color` which has two more sub properties:

- `ColorString`
- `Index`

**Goal**
I need to create a data grid where each row corresponds to an `Entry` object.  The Customer, Color, and Type properties all have comboboxes that allow for a selection of dynamically populated choices.  I need the selected item for each combobox to bind to the entry's respective property.

**Screenshot**
[image]

---

**Questions:**
**How do I properly set the data contexts for the data grid and for each combobox?**
For the data grid, I'm setting the data context programmatically to an instance of ObservableCollection.

```
private ObservableCollection<Entry> entries = new ObservableCollection<Entry>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    entries.Add(new Entry("Foo", "Customer1", new MyColor("#00000000", 1), "Type1"));
    entries.Add(new Entry("Bar", "Customer2", new MyColor("#00000000", 1), "Type2"));
    LayerMapGrid.DataContext = entries; //Set data-context of datagrid
}
```

For the color combobox, I'm using an `ObjectDataProvider` in my XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Colors" ObjectType="{x:Type local:MyColor}" MethodName="GetColors"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

This is how I bind the ObjectDataProvider

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Colors}}"/>
```

In the `MyColor` class, I've created the method below:

```
public static ObservableCollection<MyColor> GetColors()
{
    ObservableCollection<MyColor> colors = new ObservableCollection<MyColor>();
    //... Fill collection... (omitted for brevity)
    return colors;
}
```

The good news is that ALL of the above code WORKS.  However is it a good approach to the problem at hand?

This my next and more important question:
**How do I bind the selected items of the comboboxes so that `ObservableCollection<Entry>` is updated?**

I'm aware that I need to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"`, so that my source, which is the `Entry` collection is updated.

Here is my current XAML code for setting up my entire data grid.  Note:  I haven't implemented the customer and type comboboxes yet.  I'm really just concerned with the color combobox:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="LayerMapGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <!--Name Column-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <!--Customer Column-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Customer">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding CustomerName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <!--Color Column-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Color">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Colors}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Color, ElementName=LayerMapGrid, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <DockPanel Margin="2">
                                        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="1" Width="10" Height="10">
                                            <Rectangle Name="ColorRec" Fill="{Binding ColorString}"/>
                                        </Border>
                                        <TextBlock Padding="4,2,2,2" Text="{Binding ColorString}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <!--Type Column-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Type, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.  I've been banging my head on the wall for about 16 hours with this.

-Nick Miller

**EDIT:**
I found the solution (and as always immediately after requesting help), but I don't understand how it works.

In the XAML, I've changed the combobox binding to be the following:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Colors}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Color, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

What exactly is happening here?

**Why is the combobox now referring to the datagrid's data context?  Doesn't that get overriden when I set the ItemsSource to point to my `ObjectDataProvider`?**

Comment: Man your question is long! If you don't hear from me again, I didn't make it through.

Comment: Haha, thats because I wanted to elaborate thoroughly.  Anyways, I've found the problem, but have confusion with why it works.  See the end of my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I properly set the data contexts for the data grid and for each combobox?

You don't. Normally in WPF, we set the `DataContext` property on the `UserControl`, or `Window` that we are designing, *not* on individual controls. In this way, *all* the controls in the view have access to the data properties.

> How do I bind the selected items of the comboboxes so that ObservableCollection is updated?

Again, you don't do what you are doing. Rather than using an `ObjectDataProvider`, you should just have a property of type `ObservableCollection<MyColor>` in the code behind and bind to that directly. And you should be binding a `public Entries` property to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property, *not* setting the `private entries` field as the `DataContext`. You really need to read through the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further help with this.

Set the `DataContext` of `MainWindow.xaml` to itself (which generally is a not a good idea):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Entries.Add(new Entry("Foo", "Customer1", new MyColor("#00000000", 1), "Type1"));
    Entries.Add(new Entry("Bar", "Customer2", new MyColor("#00000000", 1), "Type2"));
    DataContext = this; //Set DataContext to itself so you can access properties here
}
```

Then in `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" ... />
```

The `DataTemplate`s in each row of the `DataGrid` automatically have the relevant item in the data bound collection set as the `DataContext`, so you automatically get access to the properties from the relevant class. Again... no need to set any `DataContext`s manually. If you have further questions, please read the linked article, because the answers are there.

---

UPDATE >>>

Let's be clear about something... I am *not* your personal mentor, so this will be my last reply.

> How do I overcome the combobox inheriting the data context of the data grid?

To data bind to the object that is set as the `Window.DataContext`, you just need to use a valid `Binding Path` and some basic logic:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.MyColors, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourLocalPrefix:MainWindow}}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Are you suggesting that I create some sort of wrapper class to hold the entire data context?  You said I should set the data context of the window/user control, but you also said I shouldn't set the context to itself.  I'm assuming that an instance of this wrapper class would be more suitable. (Darn, I spend half of my work day reading that MSDN page to understand what I'm doing! :P).  By the way, do you know why the the my combobox's code uses two different data contexts?  I guess it is because the combobox inherits the datagrid's context, and then it is overridden.

Comment: *Darn, I spend half of my work day reading that MSDN page to understand what I'm doing!* Nothing good comes easy. *do you know why my combobox's code uses two different data contexts?* It doesn't... there is only one `DataContext` property. *Are you suggesting that I create some sort of wrapper class to hold the entire data context?* That is customary, especially when using MVVM, which is why that is so popular. Really though, it just makes sense to data bind one object to the `DataContext` that has *all* of the properties that you want to bind to in the view.

Comment: I've created a wrapper class which contains `ObservableCollection<Entry>` and `ObservableCollection<MyColor>` as properties and I've set the MainWindow's data context to point to an instance of the wrapper.  How do I overcome the combobox inheriting the data context of the data grid?  I only need 1 instance of the color collection, and I've tried accessing it via this: `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=MyColors}`.  Using another combobox, I've been able to access the colors when the inherited data context is my wrapper class.

Comment: Gah I did it again!...I fixed it.  When I specified the source, I said that the source was `Window.MyColors` which is wrong,  because `MyColors` exists in the `DataContext` property for my Window.
Here is the correct code:
`{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.MyColors}`